# Sending a concatenated message using num_segments in Twilio

Tags: twilio

Twilio  document states that num_segments specifies the number of chunks that a single message contains. I tried using this to send a long message but i couldnt succeed. It says the message  cannot exceed 160 character limit. Has anyone sent a string longer than 160 characters as a concatenated message using num_segments in Twilio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd double check that you are using the new [Messages resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message), not the old SmsMessages resource.  The SmsMessages resource is still limited to 160 characters while the new Messages resource supports messages up to 1600 characters.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help Devin! You are awesome :) Now it works like a charm. All i did was change tclient = TwilioRestClient(account, token)
  tclient.sms.messages.create(to=sender_num, from_=receiver_num, body=body_msg) to tclient = TwilioRestClient(account, token)
  tclient.messages.create(to=sender_num, from_=receiver_num, body=body_msg)

Comment: @DevinRader Can I force twilio to just send 1 SMS even for messages longer than 160 chars?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  Concatenated SMS messages are really just device magic.  SMS itself still only allows for 160 bytes, but it lets us add metadata to messages in order to tell your device how to reassemble it to make it look like a single message.

Comment: For python api use: `client.messages.*` rather than `client.sms.messages.*`

Comment: @DevinRader, is there any way the c# api can tell me the amount of segments an sms will take before actually sending? I've created my own "calculator", but Twiio keeps sending more segments tan the calculator shows. For example, for a UCS2 message with 189 chars, the calculator gives 3 segments, but Twiio sends 4. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Devin's answer, if you're using Ruby (`twilio-ruby` gem), you just have to:

**Change**

`twilio_client.account.sms.messages.create(...)`

**to**

`twilio_client.account.messages.create(...)`

(Remove the `sms` part)